# How to use Sequelize ORM Raw queries (Inline or already prepared SQL queries) in Moleculer.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, moleculer

I am using sequelize ORM for Mysql Database. Now if I want to use Raw queries(Inline or already prepared SQL queries) in moleculer then how I can use it.

e.g,

```
SELECT user_name as UserName FROM users OR
SELECT column-names
FROM table-name1 LEFT JOIN table-name2
ON column-name1 = column-name2
WHERE condition
```

Sequelize Ref : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/raw-queries.html
Please guide me.
Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question, the docs explain how to use the raw queries.

Comment: yes.. I know that they have explained in their docs about the raw queries but wanted to know how to call through Moleculer Framework ? I am able to run the queries as below.

e.g.
broker.call("posts.find", query: { 
id:{ $in: [1, 2]}}
});

Comment: But how to execute Raw queries (Inline or already prepared SQL queries) in Moleculer.js.

Answer (score 3):

```js
    actions: {
        findRaw() {
            return this.adapter.db.query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title = 'Hello 2' LIMIT 1")
                 .then(res => res[0]);
        }
    },
```

Comment: actions: {
        findRaw() {
            return this.adapter.db.query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title = 'Hello 2' LIMIT 1")
                 .then(res => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res[0])));
        }
    },